# SSL Certificate (Push Notifications) for two apps with the same root bundle

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification

I have a project on Xcode with two targets (two apps:free version and premium version) that shares the same root bundle:

com.example.freeversion
com.example.premiumversion

Is there the option of having one SSL Certificate for push notifications for the two apps?

Comment: This link might be useful [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188274/device-tokens-for-apple-push-notifications-provider

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible as both versions in your example have different bundle identifiers:

```
com.example.freeversion 
com.example.premiumversion
```

The fact that the beginning of the ID is the same won't matter and Wildcard bundle identifiers (*) don't work with APNS.

So it looks like you'll need separate SSL certificates.