# Testflight - Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate - BadDeviceToken

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight, pushy

I'm to trying to test my push notifications while utilizing TestFlight.

I can successfully receive a push notification on a device when I deploy directly to it from Xcode. However when I deploy the app to the device via TestFlight (as an external tester) I get "BadDeviceToken".

I have created a "Universal Push Notification Client SSL Certificate" and followed [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW11) apple instructions to the letter (I think). As per link:

> "The client SSL certificate that is generated is a universal certificate that allows your app to connect to both the **development** and **production** environments."

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

**FYI:**

**Relevant Application Service:**

[image]

**iOS Certificates:**

[image]

Comment: how do you send notifications? What gives you 'BadDeviceToken' error?

Comment: For testing purposes I am sending notifications via a unit test. I am using [pushy](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy). I copy the token that is returned post app install into the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this was my silly error. I am using [Pushy](https://github.com/relayrides/pushy).

You specify the environment like so:

```
apnsClient.connect(ApnsClient.PRODUCTION_APNS_HOST);
```

Unfortunately I had specified DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST before. It would seem that when you use TestFlight you have to specify the production apns host.

Thanks for everyone that looked over the question and answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to re-create the certificates from scratch. Make sure that the certificates are production/distribution and not using APNS sandbox. Also, make sure it's on an actual approved device and not a simulator.

From the APNS Docs:

> The specified device token was bad. Verify that the request contains
>   a valid token and that the token matches the environment

Also, check out these two links (first one is old):

[iPhone APNS Device Tokens in sandbox vs. production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943722/iphone-apns-device-tokens-in-sandbox-vs-production)

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119615/send-push-notifications-to-ios-using-apns

Comment: Thanks jhack. I have created a "Universal" certificate which according to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html) can be used for "development **and** production environments". Must be missing something...? Will have a look through the links.