# Testing in-app/banner notifications

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have recently joined a startup who has been using an offshore team up until now. Our app in built in Obj-C with a PHP backend, both of which I am fairly new to (I come from a JS background). I have been wanting to make some alterations to the current in-app notifications (banners), but have been unable to figure out how to test them. I am aware that testing notifications on the simulator is not possible, and have installed the developer build to my device. However, I am still not receiving any notifications when I would normally receive them in the production build, such as when a friend posts a message. If anyone has any experience with this I would love to hear it. I am currently developing in Xcode 8.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get closed as too broad a question, but for what it's worth here are some checkpoints:

- The app is enabled for notifications in iPhone Settings
- The app is requesting a push token from APNS
  (`registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`)
- It receives a valid token from APNS and
  passes it to your PHP server (`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`)
- Your server is storing the token correctly
- Your server is triggering a push notification correctly
- Your development certificate is correct
  (read this post [iPhone APNS Device Tokens in sandbox vs. production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943722/iphone-apns-device-tokens-in-sandbox-vs-production))

If you want to test push without the server in the loop, checkout PushMeBaby (there are several on GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

**try it:**

if app is already launched in App Store: they enabled the production certificated ... and u r running the application through Xcode ,u will not get the notifications in ur device... for that u need to create IPA file for ur project and run through iTunes...